# Integration of ARToolkit SDK in iOS existing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I have created a new Xcode Project to test the artoolkit.
I have download the sdk from Git https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5. I just copy the following files (See attached image)

[image]

from there give example project.
But the its showing me the Error in ARMarker.h and ARMArkerMulti.h files when I try to build project.

[image]

I want to integrate ARToolkit SDK in one of my existing application but I have no idea where to start.

- Which files/folder I used from SDK?
- How do I create trackable?

Comment: Why don't you try the packaged download from the official page? You do not need to compile all ARToolkit to make an app that uses it.

Comment: Thanks @shalafi for reply. I have that one as well.i have already try with their Package but same error appearing.So which file i will use ?

Comment: I've only used the Android and Unity ones, never the iOS, and they all worked following the online instructions, so I'm afraid I can't help you better :-/

Comment: @Akhtar did you find out how to setup an existing iOS App to use ARToolKit?

Comment: Did anyone find a way to integrate artoolkit sdk into another ios app?

Comment: Sorry for late reply @RaimundWege and abdul rehman did't find a solution for this :(

Comment: @Akhtar you fixed this issue?

Comment: @JAK No Dear :(

Comment: @Akhtar, I want to integrate ARtoolKit as alibrary to my new Xcode project.You have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the whole sdk, Unzip it and run the Xcode project from there. I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: Is it possible to add Artoolkit as a library to new Xcode project?

Answer (score 0):

I think this error because your new project does not contain **pch** file.(Latest Xcode does not include **pch** file)So you must add **pch** file from ARToolKit iOS project.Then set the file in **build settings** of your target  like the following image:

[image]

Some additional Information: You can also note my answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333823/ios-artoolkit-xcode-implementation)